# continue sub loops after error inside promise - try/catch

Tags: javascript, loops, error-handling, promise, continue

I'm having severe doubts that the code I'm writing is an efficient/best way to achieve my goal.

I have a promise which makes an SQL query, after it's completed I loop through an array and it's sub arrays+objects. Even if any of the subloops fail for any specific reason I want the inner loops to continue executing until the entire array has been looped through. Right now I have a "try/catch" hell which I doubt is the correct way to do this. I should however say that it works as expected, but how bad code is it?

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sqlConnection.execute(
    'INSERT INTO pms (userId, message, conversationId) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
        [userid, receivedMsg, receivedConvId],
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            resolve("DEBUG: PM from "+username+" into conv "+receivedConvId+" was sucessfully inserted to DB");
        }   
    );  
}).then(() => {
    users.forEach(function(userobj, i, arr) {
        try {
            if (userobj.memberof.includes(receivedConvId)) {
                let rcptUsername = userobj.username;    
                let rcptUserid = userobj.userid;
                debug(rcptUsername+" is member of the group "+receivedConvId);
                Object.keys(userobj.sessions).forEach(function(session) {
                    try {
                    userobj.sessions[session].forEach(function(wsConn) {
                        try {   
                            debug("DEBUG: Broadcasting message to "+rcptUsername+" for connections inside session "+session);
                            wsConn.send(JSON.stringify(msgToSend));
                        } catch(err) {
                            errorHandler(err);
                        }   
                    }); 
                    } catch(err) {
                    errorHandler(err);
                }   
            }); 
        }   
    } catch(err) {
        errorHandler(err); 
     }
});
}).catch((err) => {
    debug(err);
}).then(() => {
    debug("INFO: Message broadcast finished");
});
```

The array I'm looping through could look like this:

```
[ 
{ username: 'Root',
    userid: '1',
    memberof: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    sessions: 
        { 
            pvkjhkjhkj21kj1hes5: [Array],
            '4duihy21hkk1jhhbbu52': [Array] 
        } 
},
{ 
    username: 'Admin',
    userid: '2',
    memberof: [ 1, 2, 4 ],
    sessions: 
        { 
            cg2iouoiuiou111uuok7: [Array],
            sl1l3k4ljkjlkmmmmkllkl: [Array] 
        } 
} 
]
```

Grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `wsConn` is a `https://github.com/websockets/ws` websocket - then the code you are using will only ever "detect" immediate errors anyway - any socket write failures will not be caught

You'll also be outputting "INFO: Message broadcast finished" before any of the `wsConn.send` have finished - because it's asynchronous

Fortunately `.send` has a callback, which is called back on errors or success once the send has *completed* - this solves both issues

Using promises is a good idea, except you haven't used promises for anything but the initial SQL execute, which is why you've ended up in nesting hell

I'm fairly confident (without your full code I can't be sure) that the following code will not only run, it has far less nesting

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sqlConnection.execute(
        'INSERT INTO pms (userId, message, conversationId) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
        [userid, receivedMsg, receivedConvId],
        (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve("DEBUG: PM from " + username + " into conv " + receivedConvId + " was sucessfully inserted to DB");
        }
    );
}).then(() => {
    const allConnectionsArray = users
    .filter(({memberof}) => memberof.includes(receivedConvId)) // filter out any userobj we aren't going to send to
    .map(({rcptUsername, rcptUserid, sessions}) => {
        debug(rcptUsername + " is member of the group " + receivedConvId);
        const userSessionsArray = Object.entries(sessions).map(([session, value]) => {
            return value.map((wsConn, index) => {
                return { wsConn, rcptUserid, rcptUsername, session, index };
            })
        });
        return [].concat(...userSessionsArray); // flatten the array
    });
    const promises = [].concat(...allConnectionsArray) // flatten the array
    .map(({ wsConn, rcptUserid, rcptUsername, session, index }) => {
        debug("DEBUG: Broadcasting message to " + rcptUsername + " for connections inside session " + session);
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            wsConn.send(JSON.stringify(msgToSend), err => {
                if (err) {
                    return resolve({ rcptUserid, rcptUsername, session, index, err });
                }
                resolve({ rcptUserid, rcptUsername, session, index, err: false });
            });
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(results => {
    /* results is an array of {
        rcptUserid
        rcptUsername
        session
        index //(index is the ordinal position in user.sessions array
        err //(===false if success)
    }
    */
    debug("INFO: Message broadcast finished");
}).catch(error => {
    // the only error caught here would be in the `return reject(err);` in the sql execute,
    // because any failure in wsConn.send is a resolved promise (with an error property)
    // unless I'm not seeing something obvious, they are the only possible places an error could be thrown anyway
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! The code worked flawlessly right out of the box, except for that I had to change rcptUserid/name to username and userid (to have it match the userobj key names - changed my global username/userid vars to something else too). I can see why this code is way better,  just as I thought. I'll have to examine it for some time before I understand all parts completely though. A lot of new stuff and a "modern" way of code-writing that I as a rookie isn't familiar with.